# Remove Dups then Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with a troublesome MySQL data table. I have a group of records I'm pulling out, but, the records are duplicates. I need to appropriately sum the distinct values. Here's the situation ...

Given the data

```
   identifier    category    value
       1           a          40
       1           a          20
       1           b          80
       1           c          40
       1           a          80
       2           a          20
       2           b          40
```

What I want to pull out is the following

```
   identifier    category
       1            200
       2            60
```

In this case, I want to eliminate duplicates as defined by a compound key of identifier + category using MAX on the "value" field. That leaves me with the following:

```
   identifier    category    value
       1           a          80
       1           b          80
       1           c          40
       2           a          20
       2           b          40
```

I then want to SUM "value" based on the identifier.

This is another example where I know what I need, but, I'm not sure how to do it in a single SQL statement. I could use a temp table, then run the aggregation (SUM) query on that. But, I'd like to try and get it all with one statement.

Comment: Use a subselect to get the MAX and then use SUM in the outer select.

Comment: Use the query that gets that "distinct" values as an inline view for another query. That is, your "select max... group by ... " query will be a rowsource, referenced in the FROM clause of an outer query.  The out query can do the aggregation to get the SUM. (MySQL refers to an inline view as a derived table.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get `Max` value in each `identifier + category`

```
select identifier,category,max(value)
from table1 
group by identifier,category;
```

To get the `SUM` do the aggregation on top of above result

```
select identifier,sum(value) as value
from 
(
select identifier,category,max(value) as value
from table1 
group by identifier,category
) a
group by identifier
```

- **[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2d7fc/3)**

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tested this with live data and it seems to do what I want. The challenge I'm running into is that the query is so complex with so many joins, I ultimately decided to use a temporary table first. But, the solution helped craft the two queries I needed. Thank you!!